# creating a directory and subdirectories using bash?

Tags: bash

Here's a sample output what it should look like when the bash script is executed --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfUBk.jpg .

My question is about how do we make this or what code can I use?

Comment: 1) Post the desired output in your question instead of a link to a photo. 2) Provide what you have tried so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: @Nish: Have a look at the `-p` option of *mkdir*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in a a/b a/b/c a/b/c/d; do
        mkdir "$dir" && touch "$dir/${dir##*/}"{1..100}
done
```

That is, loop through the directory names that we'd like to create, and for each directory:

1. create it, and
2. create empty files in it.

`${dir##*/}` will expand to the basename of the directory in `$dir`, e.g. to `c` if `$dir` is `a/b/c`.  The brace expansion `something{1..100}` will expand to `something1 something2 ... something100`.

A variation that is easier to expand to an arbitrary depth:

```
dir=''
for dirname in a b c d; do
        dir="${dir:-.}/$dirname"
        mkdir "$dir" && touch "$dir/${dir##*/}"{1..100}
done
```

Here, `${dir:-.}` will be replaced by `.` if `$dir` is unset or empty, which it will be on the first iteration.  This means that `$dir` will be built up to be first `./a`, then `./a/b` etc.

If you want further subdirectories, e.g. all the way down to `z`:

```
dir=''
for dirname in {a..z}; do
        dir="${dir:-.}/$dirname"
        mkdir "$dir" && touch "$dir/${dir##*/}"{1..100}
done
```

Comment: thanks for that. I executed that command but it actually only went until D[1..100] nothing after that.
"4 directories, 400 files"

Comment: @Nish See updated answer.